# write list of lists to file but each tuple has to be on a new line, using python

Tags: python

I have an ugly list of lists generated in a program,
which looks like this:

```
 a= [[93.400000000000006, "high"], [98.600000000000009, 99.0, "high"], [121.30000000000001, 124.1000000000000]]
```

I am saving it to a text file as follows:

```
with open('sample.txt','a') as outfile:
    json.dump(a,outfile)
    outfile.write("\n\n")
```

When I open the text file, the values saved are an eyesore. 
How do I save each list to a new line?

For example if I wanted to print each list to a new line, I could simply do:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    print a[i]
```

thank you

EDIT: 
OUTPUT HAS TO LOOK LIKE :

[93.400000000000006, "high"]
[98.600000000000009, 99.0, "high"]

i.e each on one line.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `json.dumps`?

Comment: you don't have a list of tuples to start with…

Comment: It depends on how you want to store the values. Do you want just to save them like this  `[93.400000000000006, "high"]` or like this `93.400000000000006,"high"`. Pleasge give us an example how your output should look like

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how would i write to file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204523/how-would-i-write-to-file-with-python)

Comment: @ChristianDean only reason: I know that we have to use json.dump for saving json data. now I had to save this list, so I json.dump was only thing I knew, so I tried and it gave no errors. Now based on the answers I understand that outfile.write with for loop can do the job. :)

Comment: @MushroomMauLa interesting question, may I ask what difference would that make, and how are they different? because that thought hadn't occurred to me till I saw your comment. :(

Comment: @hop thanks for correcting, calling it `tuples` was my mistake.

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K It just makes a diffrent when you want to read the data again because then you would have to parse the data diffrent to get the same output.

Comment: that makes sense. I must probably reconsider how I want the data, because next I want populate three columns of a table in postgresql db., row wise, that is each list[val1,val2,flag]  will go into three columns one row at a time

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K May I ask, why you would want to store your data first in a file and not directly in the database? As far as I know(I've never worked with PostgreSQL) you can interact directly from python with it

Comment: honestly, I don't know. :-( let me do some research and see if I can directly populate the db with these values instead of having extra steps. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really don't any reason here to use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.dumps). You can just use a normal `for` loop:

```
a = [
        [93.400000000000006, "high"], 
        [98.600000000000009, 99.0, "high"], 
        [111.60000000000001, 112.5, "high"]
]

with open('sample.txt', 'a') as outfile:
    for sublist in a:
        outfile.write('{}\n'.format(sublist))
```

The above code produces the output:

```
[93.400000000000006, 'high']
[98.600000000000009, 99.0, 'high']
[111.60000000000001, 112.5, 'high']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
with open('sample.txt','a') as outfile:
    for item in a:
        json.dump(item,outfile)
        outfile.write("\n\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output to be in JSON format, but want the elements of the outer list to appear on separate lines in the file, supply the `indent` keyword argument:

```
with open('sample.txt','w') as outfile:
    json.dump(a, outfile, indent=4)
```

Given a number or a whitespace string, `indent` specifies the indentation to use at each level, showing the structure of the data. By default, the output is not pretty-printed at all, to save space. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) for details. The same argument works with `json.dumps` to create a string.

Note that the JSON data format is not designed to be "embedded" in other files; you should not use the `'a'` file mode for writing JSON, and should not plan on the file containing anything else besides your one JSON value.

Another option is the [`pprint` standard library module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html), if you aren't especially concerned with the data format. `pprint.pprint` will automatically decide how to split up lines based on their length:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint([[1],[2],[3]])
[[1], [2], [3]]
>>> pprint.pprint([[1],[2],[3]], width=1) # force line-wrapping
[[1],
 [2],
 [3]]
```

It can print to a file by specifying the `stream` argument.

Finally, it is worth noting the option of iterating over the list and using `json.dump` for each line. This **does not produce valid JSON**, but instead a related data format called JSONL.

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you:

```
file=open('sample.txt','w')
for i in a:
    file.write(str(a))
    file.write("\n\n")
```